# Error while doing a select on all tables in DB2

Tags: select, db2

I'm working on `DB2` database. When I run a simple select on a table I get this error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, SQLERRMC=1;My_Table, DRIVER=4.18.60
```

I looked on the internet and some says that executing this command can solve the problem :

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE My_Table')
```

When I execute the previous SQL command I get this error:

```
[Error Code: -2216, SQL State: 01H52]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-2216, SQLSTATE=01H52, SQLERRMC=-668, DRIVER=4.18.60
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start at the end. Your second error is telling you that you're running into the same error when trying to run a REORG. If you look at [the documentation for `-2216`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql02216n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-4-117), you see this:

> ***SQL2216N***
>
> SQL error *sqlcode* occurred while reorganizing a database
>   table or its indexes.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> An error occurred during the reorganization of a database table or its
>   indexes.
>
> The utility stops processing.
>
> **User response**
>
> Look at the SQLCODE (message number) in the message for more
>   information. Make changes and resubmit the command.

So, let's look back at your second error. If you'll notice in the documentation, `sqlcode` is italicized, which means that will show up in the messages contained in `SQLERRMC`. Looking at that, it's another `-668`.

If you look at [the documentation for `-668`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00668n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-1-103), you will find your answer. Again, looking at `SQLERRMC`, the *reason-code* for the error is `1`, so we look down at what to do for reason code 1, and we get the following:

> ***SQL0668N***
>
> Operation not allowed for reason code *reason-code* on table
>   *table-name*.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Access to table *table-name* is restricted. The cause is based on the
>   following reason codes
>
> *reason-code*:
>
> 1
>
> The table is in the Set Integrity Pending No Access state. The integrity of the table is not enforced and the content of the table
>   may be invalid. An operation on a parent table or an underlying table
>   that is not in the Set Integrity Pending No Access state may also
>   receive this error if a dependent table is in the Set Integrity
>   Pending No Access state.
>
> ....
>
> **User response**
>
> 1
>
> Execute the SET INTEGRITY statement with the IMMEDIATE CHECKED option on table table-name to bring the table out of the Set Integrity
>   Pending No Access state. For a user maintained materialized query
>   table, execute the statement with the IMMEDIATE UNCHECKED option
>   instead of the IMMEDIATE CHECKED option.

Comment: Why is a reorg even necessary? I'm just trying to delete some records from a table. What is the underlying cause of this bug in DB2? All these things worked fine in Postgres. SET INTEGRITY also throws the same error. I cannot fathom why I would need to know how the internals of DB2 work to do the most basic of SQL tasks.

Answer (score 3):

CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE My_Table')

that code Not work for me.So i try and get another solution.

SET INTEGRITY FOR table_name IMMEDIATE CHECKED